# How to get monthly postcount of phpBB users with SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpbb, phpbb3

I'm new to this SQL stuff, working with phpmyadmin. I already managed to get all usernames but don't know how to get postcount and especially postcounts within a defined periode of time (month). This is what i got so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ug.`user_id`,
  u.`username`,
  pfd.`pf_full_name`
FROM
  `phpbb3_user_group` AS ug
INNER JOIN
  `phpbb3_groups` AS g ON g.group_name = 'User'
INNER JOIN
  `phpbb3_users` AS u ON u.`user_id` = ug.`user_id`
INNER JOIN
  `phpbb3_profile_fields_data` AS pfd ON pfd.`user_id` = ug.`user_id`
WHERE
  ug.`group_id` = g.`group_id` AND u.`user_type` = 0
ORDER BY
  ug.`user_id`
```

Comment: Check the manual for aggregate functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql group by month including empty months](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007363/mysql-group-by-month-including-empty-months)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT user_id FROM phpbb_users u WHERE u.user_type IN (0, 3, 1) AND u.user_regdate > 1648771200 AND (u.user_lastvisit > 0 AND u.user_lastvisit < 1651276800) ORDER BY u.user_regdate ASC

April add user sql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help would help you to make the difference between code and your explanation (which would benefit from being elaborated) more obvious - or using punctuation, capitalisation and other common habits.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please split code from text using the in editor function. Hint: use ``` on a single line before and after your SQL code which could do with a bit formatting. Than add a desription in english explaining what you do here.